# why does character_arrays.exe has stopped working error pop up?

Tags: c++, arrays, character

my code is working fine. Its showing the right results in the file but after executing the code,an error message pops up saying "character_array.exe has stopped working". Can anyone tell why that error appears??

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name[20], roll_no[20];
    int price[20], k=0;
  ifstream data;
  ofstream dout;
  char fname[4];
  char fname1[]={"dout"};
  cout<<"enter file name : ";
  cin.getline(fname, 20);
  if(strcmp(fname,fname1) !=0)
  {
      cout<<"file names do not match";
  }
  else{
  data.open("new.txt");
  while(!data.eof())
  {
      for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
      {
          data>>name[i]>>roll_no[i]>>price[i];
          k++;
      }
  }
  data.close();
   cout<<"data in the text file is:"<<endl;
  for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
  {
     cout<<name[i]<<"  "<<roll_no[i]<<"  "<<price[i]<<endl;
  }

  dout.open("output.txt");
  for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
  {
      dout<<name[i]<<"  "<<roll_no[i]<<"  "<<price[i]<<endl;
  }
  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mind sharing what you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your issue is an infinite loop, if your IDE supports breakpoints, I would recommend adding one to your while loop and seeing if it runs forever.

Comment: adding it in the while loop resolved the issue but i want to know what "character_array.exe has stopped working" means as running the code only one time shows this error and i dont know what needs to be changed.

Comment: My assumption was that your while loop ran infinitely, when this happens your program will crash as it continues to eat resources. I think there's a logic flaw somewhere that causes your while loop condition to never be met, causing it to run endlessly. When it crashes in this manner it will say "character_array.exe has stopped working"

Comment: this error doesnt occur when i remove strcmp() function, i am assuming we cannot apply string function on character array.. If we cannot use that function, how can we check if the user entered name matches the file name?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with cpp so you might want to ask strcmp with a string and an array as a separate question on stack overflow.

Comment: alright. thanks for the help though